# How to get data from a .rtf file or excel file into database(sqlite) in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, excel, ios4, sqlite, rtf

I had lots of data in a .rtf file(having usernames and passwords).How can I fetch that data into a table. I'm using sqlite3.
 I had created a "userDatabase.sql" in that I had created a table "usersList" having fields "username","password". I want to get the list of data in the "list.rtf" file in to my table "usersList". Please help me .

Thanks in advance.
Praveena.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a little parser. Re-save the .rtf as a txt-file and assume it look like this:

```
user1:pass1
user2:pass2
user5:pass5
```

Now do this (in your code):

- open the .txt file (`NSString -stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:`)
- read line by line
- for each line, fetch user and password (`NSArray -componentsSeparatedByString`)
- store user/password into your DB

Best,
Christian

Edit: for parsing excel-sheets I recommend export as CSV file and then do the same

Answer (score 0):

Parsing RTF files is mostly trivial. They're actually text, not binary (like doc pdf etc).
Last I used it, I remember the file format wasn't too difficult either.

Example:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22 Username Password\par
Username2 Password2\par
UsernameN PasswordN\par
}
```

Do a regular expression match to get the last `{ ... }` part. By sure to match `{` not `\{`.
Next, parse the text as you want, but keep in mind that:

- everything starting with a `\` is escaped, I would write a little function to unescape the text
- the special identifier \par is for a new line
- there are other special identifiers, such as `\b` which toggles bolding text
- the color change identifier, `\cfN` changes the text color according to the color table defined in the file header. You would want to ignore this identifier since we're talking about plain text.